# XXX in C++ comments

Tags: vim, comments, highlight

In vim, whenever I add a comment like this

`int somevar = 100; //XXX Some Comment Here`

The "XXX" part of my comment gets automatically highlighted. "TODO" in a comment also gets highlighted similarly. I've used these myself quite widely to mark todos/draw attention, but never bothered to learn what makes "XXX" and "TODO" special. What makes these two words special?

Are there are other special words in comments that automatically get highlighted?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/7284583/314291

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are made special by syntax files that Vim relies on to *style* various items within a source code.

For example on my machine, following default syntax file for C, (which is sourced by C++ syntax file too), contains the line

file: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/c.vim

```
syn keyword     cTodo           contained TODO FIXME XXX
```

Color and styling for `cTodo`, if you search would be defined within `c.vim` file.

For C++ the file name is `cpp.vim`, which sources (includes) `c.vim`

**Why these keywords?**
We'll I didn't research much, but programmers started to put attention catching prefixes to their comments, so that they (or someone else) can come to that area of code later (for whatever reason, as stated in the comment). Editors, like Vim, noticed this and added syntax highlighting for these prefixes to make them stand-out even more.

For that matter, most of the editors today have *editable* (or customizable) syntax highlighting. You can add your own keywords that you want highlighted in comments! (for other keywords/tokens too).

Answer (score 9):

> - **TODO** to indicate planned enhancements.
> - **XXX** to warn other programmers
>     of problematic or misguiding code.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_%28computer_programming%29#Tags).

Comment: Problem is now, the xxx from <table style="font-size:xxx-small"> is being automatically highlighted. Can't have it both ways, I guess.