# Why does my text editor suggest "XXX" when editing html

Tags: html, atom-editor

When i type in "x", my text editor, atom.io, suggests "xxx". If i select it, it simply displays

```
<!-- XXX:  -->
```

What does it mean or stand for?

Comment: Which editor are you using? Classic notepad? Notpad++?

Comment: I think you have at least one string "XXX" in your code. In this case, Atom only suggest you a list of words that match what are you typing.

Comment: I use Atom.io and I do not have such a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of #XXX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452934/what-is-the-meaning-of-xxx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a snippet provided by Atom. More about snippets: http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/

More about the meaning of XXX: [What is the meaning of #XXX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452934/what-is-the-meaning-of-xxx)

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the "autocomplete" feature in Atom.  To turn it off, go to Atom -> Preferences, select "Packages" on the left, scroll down to "autocomplete-snippets" and click the Disable button.

This will disable the autocompletion of all "snippets" but auto-completing of things like variable names etc will still work.

Comment: I think the question is less based on "why it happens" and more out of interest "what does the XXX stand for?"